# List slicing in C#

Tags: c#, python, arrays, slice

I came across this syntax in a python script and saw that it is called a slice assignment. How do you write this syntax in C#?

```
self.nav[:] = []
```

Comment: For those who don't speak python, this assignment replaces the content of the `nav` array (or list) with the contents of the array (or list) on right hand side. So `nav[:] = []` essentially clears the array/list.

Answer (score 6):

C# does not have a slicing assignment operator, but you can use the methods provided by `List<T>` instead:

```
list[a:b] = otherList
```

is equivalent to

```
list.RemoveRange(a,b-a);
list.InsertRange(a, otherList);
```

Or, in the spacial case of

```
list[:] = []
```

you can just write

```
list.Clear();
```

---

Technically, you could write your own list class that inherits from `List<T>` and emulates pythons behavior (at least partly):

```
public class ExtendedList<T> : List<T> 
{
    public IEnumerable<T> this[int start, int end] 
    {
        get 
        { 
            return this.Skip(start).Take(end - start); 
        }
        set 
        {
            int num = end - start;
            RemoveRange(start, Count - num > 0 ? num : 0);
            InsertRange(start, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Python does start and end indexes.  The `RemoveRange` method takes the start index and count, not the end index.

Comment: @juharr fixed that

Comment: Also I think the special case is `list[:] = []`

Comment: So self.nav[:] = [] is the equivalent to nav.Clear(), it's just clearing out the list?